# Java PreparedStatement.setDate(), query return no result

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date, prepared-statement

I tried using PreparedStatement.setDate method to input Date object into an SQL query run on Oracle Db.
The problem is no matter what parameter I choose for the Date, the result is always empty.

The SQL query:

```
Select (TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'YYYY,MM,DD')) transaction_date_graph, \
(TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'DD MON YYYY')) transaction_date_view, \
sum(trans_amount) amount from ar_customer_balance_itf \
where transaction_date>=? and transaction_date<=? \
group by transaction_date ORDER BY transaction_date
```

The java code:

```
public List<Map<String, String>> queryData(String query) {

List<Date> dates = analyseDate(query);
ResultSet rs = null;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
int count = 0;
List<Map<String, String>> propertyList = new LinkedList<Map<String, String>>();
try {
    if (dates.size()==2) // If there are two dates in the query
    {   
        stmt_dateRange.setDate(1, dates.get(0));
        stmt_dateRange.setDate(2, dates.get(1));
        rs = stmt_dateRange.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("Executed query.");
    } else if (dates.size()==1) // If there is only one date
    {   
        stmt_dateStart.setDate(1, dates.get(0));
        rs = stmt_dateStart.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("Executed query.");
    }

    rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Map<String, String> fieldMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            if (rs.getString(i) == null)
                break;
            fieldMap.put(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i).toLowerCase(),
                    rs.getString(i));
        }
        propertyList.add(fieldMap);
        count++;
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Query result: " + count + " rows");
return propertyList;
```

}

The input Date parameter are correct and it does return proper result when I test it on DbVisualizer.

Thanks,
Minh

Comment: Oracle date columns are only recorded to the second while in Java they have milliseconds.  When you create your dates in Java, are they to the second.  I would suggest cutting this down to a minmal example so you can debug. Try this: a) hardcode the dates, b) remove the <= clause and see what you get back, c) put the <= back, and then remove the >= clause and see what you get back.

Comment: I used toDate function and hardcoded test it with the following

`Select (TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'YYYY,MM,DD')) transaction_date_graph, 
(TO_CHAR(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM-D')) transaction_date_view, 
sum(trans_amount) amount from ar_customer_balance_itf
where transaction_date >= to_date('01/01/2001','DD/mm/YYYY' 
and transaction_date < to_date('03/10/2013','DD/mm/YYYY')
group by transaction_date ORDER BY transaction_date`

And it work just fine.